# Is there a Union in Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics

Can I contain two different types in a collection? For example, can I have List< String U Integer > ?

Comment: A contra-question: why would you have two *different* types in a **collection**?

Comment: @BalusC - A use case for such a construct that I have run into is a model object. e.g. in a REST API, that corresponds to the Data Transfer Object (DTO) representing a protobuf message with a `oneOf` field. A `oneOf` is essentially a union. It can contain one of a number of specified different types. A value of any of those types occupies the same memory and only one type can be stored at a time. It seems to be analogous to the `union` in C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer? No. You can (of course) have a `List` of `Objects`, but then you can put *anything* in it, not just `String` or `Integer` objects.

You could create a list of container objects, and that container object would contain either an `Integer` or `String` (perhaps via generics). A little more hassle.

```
public class Contained<T> {
   T getContained();
}
```

and implement `Contained<Integer>` and `Contained<String>`.

Of course, the *real* question is why you want to do this? I would expect a collection to contain objects of the same type, and then I can iterate through and perform actions on these objects without worrying what they are. Perhaps your object hierarchy needs further thought?

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing something like functional programming in Java 8 or above, you may want to try [JavaSealedUnions](https://github.com/pakoito/JavaSealedUnions):

```
Union2.Factory<String, Integer> factory = GenericUnions.doubletFactory();
Union2<String, Integer> strElem = factory.first("hello");
Union2<String, Integer> intElem = factory.second(3);
List<Union2<String, Integer>> list = Array.asList(strElem, intElem);
for (Union2<String, Integer> elem : list) {
    elem.continued(
        strElem -> System.out.println("string: " + strElem),
        intElem -> System.out.println("integer: " + intElem));
}
```

Haven't tested this, but I think you got the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. You have a couple of alternatives, though:

- You can use a List < Object > and stash whatever you like; or
- You can use a List < Class-with-2-members > and put your data in one of those class members.

**EDIT:** Example.

```
class UnionHolder {
  public String stringValue;
  public int intValue;
}

List < UnionHolder > myList 
...
```

Of course you'll need a bit of additional code to figure out which kind of data to pull out of the UnionHolder object you just got out of your list. One possibility would be to have a 3rd member which has different values depending on which it is, or you could, say, have a member function like

```
public boolean isItAString() { return (this.stringValue != null }
```

Comment: Could you please explain the second option?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the nice answers already provided ...

---

Possibly, you have the two data types in your algorithm. But **you may not have to put them in the same list...**

Creating two typed lists could be the clearer for your algorithm, you would still keep the "type-safeness" and carry all your data. Two code samples follow, the second grouping the two lists in a MyData object.

```
public class Algorithm1 {

  public void process(List<String> strings, List<Integer> integers) {
    ...
  }

}

--------------------------------------

public class DataPair {

  public List<String> strings;
  public List<Integer> integers;

}

public class Algorithm2 {

 public void process(DataPair dataPair) {
   ...
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

what you're decribing is the perfect use case for the [Visitor pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor)

- 100% statically type-checked
- doesn't need Java 8 or above

usage:

```
List<UnionType> unionTypes = Arrays
    .asList(new StringContainer("hello"), new IntegerContainer(4));

for (UnionType unionType : unionTypes) {
    unionType.when(new UnionType.Cases<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer is(StringContainer stringContainer) {
            // type-specific handling code
        }

        @Override
        public Integer is(IntegerContainer integerContainer) {
            // type-specific handling code
        }
    });
}
```

boilerplate code:

```java
interface UnionType {
    <R> R when(Cases<R> c);
    interface Cases<R> {
        R is(StringContainer stringContainer);
        R is(IntegerContainer integerContainer);
    }
}

class StringContainer implements UnionType {

    private final String value;
    public StringContainer(String value) { this.value = value; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }

    @Override
    public <R> R when(Cases<R> cases) {
        return cases.is(this);
    }
}

class IntegerContainer implements UnionType {

    private final Integer value;
    public IntegerContainer(Integer value) { this.value = value; }
    public Integer getValue() { return value; }

    @Override
    public <R> R when(Cases<R> cases) {
        return cases.is(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No. Think about it this way: with generics, the whole idea is to provide type safety. That would not be possible if you could put Objects of different types into it.

You can use the non-generic `java.util.List` for your purpose.

If you want to ensure that only `String` or `Integer` objects enter the list, you could create your own List implementation like so:

```
public class MySpecialList {
   private List list= new LinkedList();
   ...
   public void add(final String string) {
       list.add(string);
   }

   public void add(final Integer integer) {
       list.add(integer);
   }
   ...
   // add rest of List style methods
}
```

**Drawback**: you loose the `List` interface clarity...

Comment: "with generics, the whole idea is to provide type safety. That would not be possible if you could put Objects of different types into it". Downvoted because of this. Union types might as well be type-safe (regardless if such implementations exist).