# Limit upper bound to one of given types in Java generic method

Tags: java, generics

```
class ExceptionA extends Error{}
class ExceptionB extends SomeException{}
class ExceptionC extends Exception{}

class D extends Exception {
  public D(ExceptionA a){..}
  public D(ExceptionB b){..}
  public D(ExceptionC c){..}
}

void someMethodSomewhere() {
  try{
    ....
  } catch (ExceptionA a) {
    throw new D(a);
  } catch (ExceptionB b) {
    throw new D(b)
  } catch (ExceptionC c) {
    throw new D(c)
  }
}
```

In the above snippet, can I generify the constructor `D()`? I want to bound the generic type to be one of `ExceptionA`,`ExceptionB` or `ExceptionC` or their subtypes so that I can combine the catch blocks.

```
catch(ExceptionA | ExceptionB | ExceptionC e) {
  throw new D(e);
}
```

Something like

```
public <T extends ExceptionA | ExceptionB | ExceptionC> D(T e){..}
```

I know there is no `|` in multiple bounds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697562/is-there-a-union-in-java-generics

Comment: How will you implement this method if `A`,`B` and `C` don't `implements` a common `interface`?

Comment: Can A, B, and C implement some interface?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Would implementing an interface actually work? Say `A=String` and `B=Integer`. Wouldn't that be weird?

Comment: @DebosmitRay in this case, what would this magic method do?

Comment: @SkinnyJ that was my initial thought, but then anything implementing that interface can invoke the method.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Haha that was exactly what I was wondering. Maybe use a bunch of `instanceof` to see if both are of the same type.

Comment: @DebosmitRay sadly that doesn't really help as it doesn't provide any compile time safety.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, it doesn't provide safety at the class level, but it does send a message to any clients that it can only be used with certain types. Not that I'm defending this strategy, just pointing out that it's not completely useless.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ah! Yes. Missed that one. I think Andy Turner's answer is pretty much the most you can do

Comment: Thanks! I just updated the original question to reflect the actual usage. While Andy Turner's answer helps in the implementation side, I actually want to simplify the consumer side

Comment: The type of the `e` in a multi-catch is the lowest common supertype of the caught exceptions, i.e. `Throwable` for the above class hierarchy. Why does it *really* matter to you if the constructor is called with a different exception type?

Comment: @AndyTurner I want to wrap only these three exceptions to be wrapped in D but others to be declared in the method signature. Having a constructor that takes `Exception` will let someone to add another undesired exception to the catch list.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that you can make it "really" generic with that constraint.

The only way that I can think is to keep the three overloads, but have *those* call a private, unbounded generic method:

```
class Utils {
  public final A add(A a1, A a2){ return addInternal(a1, a2); }
  public final B add(B b1, B b2){ return addInternal(b1, b2); }
  public final C add(C c1, C c2){ return addInternal(c1, c2); }

  private <T> T addInternal(T a1, T a2) { .. }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this helps to simplify the implementation. But let me add more details on where and why I need this.