# Parameterize a class with one of a fixed set of types

Tags: java, class, generics, java-8

Say I have a generic class `Foo` which can hold an object of type `T`. Furthermore, let's say I *only* want to be able to instantiate the class with objects that are one of two types. Finally, let's say that the lowest common upper bound of these two types is a type that has many more subclasses than those two types that I want to allow, so I can't simply specify an upper bound for the type parameter (as in `class Foo<T extends Something>`), because then I would allow to instantiate the class with other types than the two I expect.

For illustration, let's say I want `Foo` to hold *only* either a `String` or an `Integer`. The lowest common upper bound is `Object`, so specifying an upper bound won't do the trick.

Certainly, I could do something along the lines of

```
class Foo<T> {

    private T obj;

    public Foo(T obj) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (!(obj instanceof String || obj instanceof Integer)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        }
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

However, in this case, I can still call the constructor with *any* object; if I try to instantiate it with something that is neither a `String` nor an `Integer`, I will get an exception at *runtime*.

I would like to do better. I would like the compiler to infer statically (i.e., at *compile time*) that I can only instantiate this class with objects that are either `String` or `Integer`.

I was thinking something along those lines might do the trick:

```
class Foo<T> {

    private T obj;

    public Foo(String s) {
        this((T) s);
    }

    public Foo(Integer i) {
        this((T) i);
    }

    private Foo(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

This works, but it looks really, really odd. The compiler warns (understandably) about unchecked casts. Of course I could suppress those warnings, but I feel this is not the way to go. In addition, it looks like the compiler can't actually *infer* the type `T`. I was surprised to find that, with the latter definition of class `Foo`, I could do this, for instance:

```
Foo<Character> foo = new Foo<>("hello");
```

Of course, the type parameter should be `String` here, not `Character`. But the compiler lets me get away with the above assignment.

1. Is there a way to achieve what I want, and if yes, how?
2. Side question: why does the compiler let me get away with the assignment to an object of type `Foo<Character>` above without even so much as a *warning* (when using the latter definition of class `Foo`)? :)

Comment: Thanks. I do not actually have access to `A` or `B`, so I can't make them implement an interface. :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Union in Java Generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697562/is-there-a-union-in-java-generics)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `static` factory method to prevent compiler warning.

```
class Foo<T> {

    private T obj;

    public static Foo<String> of(String s) {
        return new Foo<>(s);
    }

    public static Foo<Integer> of(Integer i) {
        return new Foo<>(i);
    }

    private Foo(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

Now you create instance using:

```
Foo<String> foos = Foo.of("hello");

Foo<Integer> fooi = Foo.of(42);

Foo<Character> fooc = Foo.of('a'); // Compile error
```

However the following are still valid since you can declare a Foo of any type T, but not instantiate it:

```
Foo<Character> fooc2;

Foo<Character> fooc3 = null;

Foo<Object> fooob1;

Foo<Object> fooob2 = null;
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. one word: interface. You want your Z to wrap either A or B. Create an interface implementing the smallest common denominator of A and B. Make your A and B implement that interface. There's no other sound way to do that, AFAIK. What you already did with your constructors etc. is the only other possibility, but it comes with the caveats you already noticed (having to use either unchecked casts, or static factory wrappers or other code smells).

<sub>note: If you can't directly modify `A` and/or `B`, create wrapper classes `WA` and `WB`for them beforehand.</sub>

example:

```
interface Wrapper {
    /* either a marker interface, or a real one - define common methods here */
}

class WInt implements Wrapper {
    private int value;
    public WInt( int value ) { this.value = value; }
}

class WString implements Wrapper {
    private String value;
    public WString( String value ) { this.value = value; }
}

class Foo<T> {   
    private Wrapper w;   
    public Foo(Wrapper w) { this.w = w; }
}
```

2. because you call your `private Foo(T obj)` due to diamond type inference. As such, it's equal to calling `Foo<Character> foo = new Foo<Character>("hello");`

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is one way to go, but it creates a bit of overhead, so I gave preference to @Andreas 's solution.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa I don't want to argue this, because Java already went the factory way somewhere around J7, but, honestly, having factory instead of c-tors when there's no real factory benefit (e.g. caching, reuse, extensive static context) makes the *caller* (code consumer) life's much more harder, due to semantic noise and possible `static` problems (unability to abstract the creation with `newInstance` etc.). I agree with Sweeper - your problem is not with Java here, but with a broken abstraction.

Comment: Here's the thing. Actually, I *could* just use an upper bound on `T` and not worry about what `Foo` is instantiated with, even if it's something "unexpected": My implementation can handle it just fine. It's just that, in the big picture of the application, it wouldn't make sense to instantiate `Foo` with anything else, so I simply wanted to prevent myself from accidentally doing so. But after thinking about it some more, I guess I just shouldn't worry: `Foo` doesn't really care, and if some outside method wants to instantiate `Foo` with something else, why should `Foo` care? :) Thanks again!

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa I agree with you, especially if you note the runtime caveat of type erasure: `Foo` doesn't care indeed, because `T` is actually an `Object` under the hood for the entire time!

Answer (score 1):

Generics is not suitable here.

Generics are used when *any* class can be used as the type. If you *only* allow `Integer` and `String`, you should not use generics. Create two classes `FooInteger` and `FooString` instead.

The implementations should be pretty different anyway. Since `Integer`s and `String`s are very different things and you would probably handle them differently. "But I am handling them the same way!" you said. Well then what's wrong with `Foo<Double>` or `Foo<Bar>`. If you can handle `Integer` and `String` with the same implementation, you probably can handle `Bar` and `Double` and anything else the same way as well.

Regarding your second question, the compiler will see that you want to create a `Foo<Character>`, so it tries to find a suitable overload. And it finds the `Foo(T)` overload to call, so the statement is perfectly fine as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, yes, I could handle `Foo<Double>` and `Foo<Bar>` with the same implementation. I simply want to prevent the possibility to instantiate such objects because they don't make sense in the application logic - i.e., just for safety reasons. Also, note that `String` and `Integer` were only examples. In reality, there's many more types that I want to allow, so creating a class for each one would create *a lot* of overhead. :)

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa if that is the case, you should rethink the abstraction, because it's obviously broken. `Foo` doesn't make any real sense in this context. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697562/is-there-a-union-in-java-generics#1697565 covers the very same issue, and the answer is almost the same - try to figure a better abstraction for your data instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Long story short: You are trying to create a union of two classes in java generics which is not possible but there are some workarounds.
   [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697562/is-there-a-union-in-java-generics#1697565)
2. Well the compiler uses the Character class in T parameter. Then the String constructor is used where String is casted to T (Character in this case).
   Trying to use the private field obj as a Character will most likely result in an error as the saved value is an instance of the final class String.

Comment: Thanks to you. Yours was the most clear explanation concerning point 2. Makes sense to me!