# Is it possible to serialize a generic class like this?

Tags: java, class, generics, serialization, hierarchy

I have been trying for a week to serialize a generic class hierarchy where the level of abstraction is very high in my opinion. I have tried the JSON format and the Jackson tool, also with GSON. Now I am trying with the basic java serialization mechanism, implementing the "Serializable" interface. Honestly, so far I have not been able to correctly deserialize complex generic objects like this one:

```
public class GenericObject<T>  implements  Serializable {    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 23L;
    
    private Class<T> object1;
    private GenericObject<?> object2; 
        
}
```

Note, that the parameter T and sign "?" can become a "GenericObject", i.e., something like this:

```
GenericObject< GenericObject <String> > object1 = null;
GenericObject< GenericObject <Integer> > object2 = null;
                      
 object2.setObject2(object1);  
 object2.setObject2(object2);
```

As deep as desired.

The other problem is that the "?" sign makes the problem even more complex because it allows there is  more than one simple java type in a recursive definition of the data type. For example:

```
GenericObject< GenericObject <String> > 
 GenericObject< GenericObject <Integer> >
```

Then, when I try to deserialize, I cannot know precisely the datatype that was used when serializing and this causes errors when trying to cast to get the deserialized objects.

Any ideas on how to deal with this problem are welcome.

Comment: What errors do you get? Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `object1` field in your class GenericObject in order to get the info you need to de-serialize in a correct way.

For example:

```
GenericObject< GenericObject <String> > object1 = ...;
GenericObject< GenericObject <Integer> > object2 = ...;
                      
 object2.setObject2(object1);  
 object2.setObject2(object2);
```

Then you could check like:

```
if(GenericObject.class.isAssigNableFrom(object1.getObject1()){
    //here you can deserialize according to the type
}
else if(String.class.isAssigNableFrom(object1.getObject1()){
    //here you can deserialize according to the type
}
else{
     //well you have the idea ;-)
   ....
```

If this is complex (maybe the universe of objects you require to use is huge) you can do some more complex as well, [check the visitor pattern like this answer illustrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62092235/1917237).

Cheers.